# How to disable internationalization for all bundle's all routes when using JMSI18nRoutingBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization

I use [Symfony2's JMSI18nRoutingBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle) to allow automatic internationalization of my routes. Individual route internationalization can be disabled in routing.yml as follows

```
index:
  pattern: /
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeBaseBundle:Welcome:indexRedirector }
  options:
    i18n: false
```

However, I normally annotate routes in the controllers and define just a prefix in routing.yml:

```
AcmeApiBundle:
  resource: "@AcmeApiBundle/Controller/"
  type:     annotation
  prefix:   /api
  options:
    i18n: false
```

In this case, disabling internationalization does not work properly and routes get matched only by adding the locale as a prefix for the URLs.

How to disable the internationalization for the all URLs in the bundle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify the option in the annotations. Something like:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", options={"i18n" = false})
 */
```

Comment: Whoh, strange, because I think I tested that already... too obvious answer. ;) Thanks!